# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (body ) specified for Comment

Tags: django

I am new to Django, Am receiving error as written in title. i google it but i cant found any thing.actually what i whant to do is just an add "Comment" to my blog site. i add my code as follows. and thank you 
my files:

```
#form.py

from django import forms
from django.db import models
from blog.models import Comment


class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body ')

#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('published', 'Published'),
            )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date="publish")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,      
    default="draft")

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
            self.publish.strftime('%m'),
            self.publish.strftime('%d'),
            self.slug])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Comment by {} on {}".format(self.name, self.post)

#viwes.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage,\
 PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    object_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
 'blog/post/list.html',
 {'page': page,
 'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
    status='published',
    publish__year=year,
    publish__month=month,
    publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':         
post,'comments':
comments,'comment_form': comment_form})

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "    
                            {}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'],
                                                                post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments:     
{}'.format(post.title, post_url,
cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com',
                                                         [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
 'form': form,
  'sent': sent})


def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "    
                {}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'],                                                                 
                                                    post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: 
                                {}'.format(post.title, post_url,                                                                         
                                            cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com',
                      [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
 'form': form})

#EROR

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.  
    <locals>.wrapper at 0x0435D198>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226 , in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-        
    packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",         line 374, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",     line 361, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",     line 81, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
                return check_resolver(resolver)
       File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
            for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35,     in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line  35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
       File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
    _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\project\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
        url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
          File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50,  
    in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in 
    _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\project\mysite\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
        from . import views
      File "C:\project\mysite\blog\views.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm
      File "C:\project\mysite\blog\forms.py", line 16, in <module>
        class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
      File "C:\Python3.5.2\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 257, in __new__
        raise FieldError(message)
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (body ) specified for     Comment
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to remove a white space at the end of `'body '` field, where you should have `'body'` like below:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

Answer (score 7):

The same error also occurs if a model field with `editable=False` is included in a form's fields. Removing the `editable` attribute on the model field fixes the error.

Comment: that possible. but my problem was in 'body' words. i should not leave a space. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I wasted a lot of time because I accidentally put a comma after the field definition in Model

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have any white space, then make "editable=TRUE" in models.py file.
for example:

```
class profile(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, editable=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, editable=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, editable=True)
```

and then re-lunch your development server.

Answer (score 1):

*remove the space in 'body '*
*it will look like this*

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a variant of this problem where the spelling of the field name in the form was the same as in the model. And still I got the error.

I had declared the model field like this:

```
  body = BooleanField(name="The comment's body text")
```

The mistake was to say `name` where I wanted to say `verbose_name`.

As a result, there was indeed no field called `body` in the model, just like the error message claimed, rather the field was now called something much longer.